# Reading the spss file java

Tags: java, code-analysis, analysis, spss, spss-modeler

```
  SPSSReader reader = new SPSSReader(args[0], null);
            Iterator it = reader.getVariables().iterator();
            while (it.hasNext())
             {
                System.out.println(it.next());
            }
```

I am using this SPSSReader to read the spss file. Here,every string is printed with some junk characters appended with it.

Obtained Result :

```
StringVariable: nameogr(nulltpc{)(10)
NumericVariable: weightppuo(nullf{nd)
DateVariable: datexsgzj(nulllanck)
DateVariable: timeppzb(null|wt{l)
DateVariable: datetimegulj{(null|ns)
NumericVariable: commissionyrqh(nullohzx)
NumericVariable: priceeub{av(nullvlpl)
```

Expected Result :

```
 StringVariable: name (10)
 NumericVariable: weight
 DateVariable: date
 DateVariable: time
 DateVariable: datetime
 NumericVariable: commission
 NumericVariable: price
```

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried recreating the issue and found the same thing.
Considering that there is a licensing for that library (see [here](http://spss.pmstation.com/spssr_price.jsp)), I would assume that this might be a way of the developers to ensure that a license is bought as the regular download only contains a demo version as evaluation (see [licensing before the download](http://spss.pmstation.com/spssr_download.jsp)).

As that library is rather old (copyright of the website is 2003-2008, requirement for the library is Java 1.2, no generics, Vectors are used, etc), I would recommend a different library as long as you are not limited to the one used in your question.

After a quick search, it turned out that there is an open source spss reader [here](https://github.com/bedatadriven/spss-reader) which is also available through Maven [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.bedatadriven.spss/spss-reader/1.2).

Using the example on the github page, I put this together:

```
import com.bedatadriven.spss.SpssDataFileReader;
import com.bedatadriven.spss.SpssVariable;

public class SPSSDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            SpssDataFileReader reader = new SpssDataFileReader(args[0]);

            for (SpssVariable var : reader.getVariables()) {
                System.out.println(var.getVariableName());
            }

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I wasn't able to find stuff that would print `NumericVariable` or similar things but as those were the classnames of the library you were using in the question, I will assume that those are not SPSS standardized. If they are, you will either find something like that in the library or you can open an issue on the github page.

Using the `employees.sav` file from [here](https://www.spss-tutorials.com/spss-opening-data-with-syntax/) I got this output from the code above using the open source library:

```
resp_id
gender
first_name
last_name
date_of_birth
education_type
education_years
job_type
experience_years
monthly_income
job_satisfaction
```

No additional characters no more!

**Edit** regarding the comment:

That is correct. I read through some SPSS stuff though and from my understanding there are only string and numeric variables which are then formatted in different ways. The version published in maven only gives you access to the typecode of a variable (to be honest, no idea what that is) but the github version (that does **not** appear to be published on maven as 1.3-SNAPSHOT unfortunately) does after write- and printformat have been introduced.

You can clone or download the library and run `mvn clean package` (assuming you have maven installed) and use the generated library (found under `target\spss-reader-1.3-SNAPSHOT.jar`) in your project to have the methods `SpssVariable#getPrintFormat` and `SpssVariable#getWriteFormat` available.

Those return an `SpssVariableFormat` which you can get more information from. As I have no clue what all that is about, the best I can do is to link you to the source [here](https://github.com/bedatadriven/spss-reader/blob/master/src/main/java/com/bedatadriven/spss/SpssVariableFormat.java) where references to the stuff that was implemented there should help you further (I assume that [this link](https://www.gnu.org/software/pspp/pspp-dev/html_node/Variable-Record.html#Variable-Record) referenced to in the documentation of `SpssVariableFormat#getType` is probably the most helpful to determine what kind of format you have there.

If absolutely NOTHING works with that, I guess you could use the demo version of the library in the question to determine the stuff through `it.next().getClass().getSimpleName()` as well but I would resort to that only if there is no other way to determining the format.

Comment: I used the thing you asked me to. But it returns only two types : either String or Double. Now I am unable to find if the given value is "date" or some double value.

Comment: Yeah, you were totally correct. That new jar does the job. :)

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure, but looking at your code, `it.next()` is returning a `Variable` object.

There has to be some method to be chained to the `Variable` object, something like `it.next().getLabel()` or `it.next().getVariableName()`. `toString()` on an Object is not always meaningful. Check `toString()` method of `Variable` class in SPSSReader library.

Comment: Very simple to look up the [javadoc](http://spss.pmstation.com/docs/spssr/api/index.html) for `SPSSReader` and discover the answer - in my opinion. Mohamed has helped you with some of the available methods, like `getLabel()`.

Comment: I checked what you asked me to. The toString() returns this.getClassName() + ": " + this.getName() + "(" + this.getLabel() + ")". Even if i remove this.getLabel(), it will print "nameogr" instead of "name " .

Comment: @Mohamed Anees A ,Could you help me find it ?